# Display a div at a certain width and resize smaller when browser windows shrinks. Without Javascript

Tags: html, css

I like to display a div at width, say 900px initially and when the browser window shrinks below 900px, the div shrinks with it. I like to do this without using Javascript. I tried adding min-width:0px to the div but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

So you want a [max-width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths)?

By default a div is `width: auto` and using a standard block box, so it will expand to fill the available horizontal space. max-width will constrain it.

Comment: I think setting a width with % might help too

Comment: How do you use % to get 900px if different users have their browsers open at different widths and with different resolutions?

Comment: max-width doesn't cause div to resize.

Comment: @Tony: Because width and max-width are different properties

Comment: @Tony, use max-width, don't set width

Comment: I agree with `max-width` and whether one also sets a % to `width` really depends upon the application of what is trying to be produced with the div.